# Table out of page margin

Tags: tables, macros, margins

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


\newcounter{question}
\setcounter{question}{0}

\newcommand\Q{%
\refstepcounter{question}
\paragraph{Question \thequestion.}
}

\newcommand\A{%
\smallskip
}

\Q Question.

\A

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \hline
        ~ & HR application & Manufacturing application \\
        \hline
        Agency monitoring & \multicolumn{2}{l}{CIO over two units} \\
        Agency bonding & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Units over CIO} \\
        Agency residual loss & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Dissatisfaction, misunderstandings...} \\
        \hline
        Transaction cost & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Search company, contract stipulation, relationship with outsourcer (communications, meetings...)} \\
        \hline
        Decision & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Collection and communications} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I wrap the table inside the page margins centralizing it and to get a new line if the text is too much to be contained inside the column margins?

[image]

[image]

UPDATE1:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \toprule
                      & HR application \hfill Manufacturing application \\
    \hline
    Agency monitoring & CIO over two units     \\ 
    Agency bonding    & Units over CIO          \\
    Agency residual loss & Dissatisfaction, misunderstandings... \\
    Transaction cost  & Search company, contract stipulation, relationship with 
    outsourcer communications, meetings \\
    Decision          & Collection and communications \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

gives me the following result

[image]

However I need that `HR application` and `Manufacturing application` create two different columns.

This table

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lll}
    \toprule
    Agency monitoring & Control employees & Control company service \\
    Agency bonding & Employees' report & Company report \\
    Agency residual loss & None & None \\
    \hline
    Transaction cost & None & Search company, establish contract \\
    \hline
    Decision & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs \\
    \hline
    KPI1 - Cost & Cost of employees and equipment & Cost of service \\
    KPI2 - Quality & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Level of cleanness} \\
    KPI3 - Frequency & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Frequency of cleaning, n times per week a place is cleaned} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

include columns with text out of table margins. Is it possible to have all two tables aligned with the paragraphs?

[image]

Comment: wish you had added the entire able in the first place--fragments of information interrupt the flow--suggest to accept the answer below and post a fresh question with complete requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Is this what you look for

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{caption,tabularx,booktabs}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXl}

    \hline \rowcolor{green!20}
                      & HR application & Manufacturing application \\
    Agency monitoring & CIO over two units &    \\ 
    Agency bonding    & Units over CIO      &    \\
    Agency residual loss & Dissatisfaction, misunderstandings...& \\
    Transaction cost  & Search company, contract stipulation, relationship 
    with outsourcer communications, meetings &\\
    Decision          & Collection and communications &\\        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

### OR

[image]

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule \rowcolor{green!20}
                  & HR application \hfill Manufacturing application \\
Agency monitoring & CIO over two units     \\ 
Agency bonding    & Units over CIO          \\
Agency residual loss & Dissatisfaction, misunderstandings... \\
Transaction cost  & Search company, contract stipulation, relationship with 
outsourcer communications, meetings \\
Decision          & Collection and communications \\        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: The second one is what I was looking for but it gives me a warning "Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide)". Can you explain why your solution works and what is that warning?

Comment: paste your code as an edit to your original question--only then some analysis

Comment: I've added the previous table and another one but there's one more problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It is not clear if the text in the cells of the third colum is approximately equal long As in the second column, but I anticipatated that it is. Therefore I select equal width of both `X` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % <--- for smart hyphenation of cell's contents
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \setcellgapes{2pt} % <---
    \makegapedcells    % <--- for more vertical spaces around thext in cells
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{2}{>{\RaggedRight}X} @{}}
    \toprule
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Application}}   \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
                    & \thead{HR}         & \thead{Manufacturing} \\
    \midrule
Agency monitoring   & CIO over two units    &    \\
Agency bonding      & Units over CIO        &    \\
Agency residual loss 
                    & Dissatisfaction, misunderstandings \dots
                                            &   \\
Transaction cost    & Search company, contract stipulation,
                      relationship with outsourcer communications, meetings 
                                            &   \\
Decision            & Collection and communications 
                                            &   \\        
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```