# Tabularx paragraph alignment and column of content out of margin

Tags: tables, macros, margins, tabularx

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx,booktabs}


\begin{document}


\newcounter{question}
\setcounter{question}{0}

\newcommand\Q{%
\refstepcounter{question}
\paragraph{Question \thequestion.}
}

\newcommand\A{%
\smallskip
}


\Q A medium company (40 people, all located in offices) is considering two options for cleaning the offices...

\A 

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \hline
    ~ & Insourced & Outsourced \\
    \hline
    Agency monitoring & Control employees & Control company service \\
    Agency bonding & Employees' report & Company report \\
    Agency residual loss & None & None \\
    \hline
    Transaction cost & None & Search company, establish contract \\
    \hline
    Decision & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs \\
    \hline
    KPI1 - Cost & Cost of employees and equipment & Cost of service \\
    KPI2 - Quality & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Level of cleanness} \\
    KPI3 - Frequency & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Frequency of cleaning, n times per week a place is cleaned} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lll}
    \toprule
    Agency monitoring & Control employees & Control company service \\
    Agency bonding & Employees' report & Company report \\
    Agency residual loss & None & None \\
    \hline
    Transaction cost & None & Search company, establish contract \\
    \hline
    Decision & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs \\
    \hline
    KPI1 - Cost & Cost of employees and equipment & Cost of service \\
    KPI2 - Quality & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Level of cleanness} \\
    KPI3 - Frequency & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Frequency of cleaning, n times per week a place is cleaned} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

How can I align the second table to the paragraph created by the `\Q` and `\A`  commands centralizing it to the page and to wrap the content into the column margins without getting rid of the `\multicolumn`?

[image]

Comment: Just add a `\noindent`command before `\begin{tabularx}.

Comment: the first table is nested in a `table` environment the second is not -- this creates the indent--simply put the second table also within the `\begin{table}.....\end{table}` -- the 2 tables will be now aligned

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the `X` column type tabularx provides instead of the `l` column type.
This takes care of the lines not going over the side of the table. You can use the same for the multicolumn, with a little fixing found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236156/172164). In order for the whole table to be centered, like Sveinung commented, `\noindent` should do the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,multirow,ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{2}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} @{}}
    \toprule
    Agency monitoring & Control employees & Control company service \\
    Agency bonding & Employees' report & Company report \\
    Agency residual loss & None & None \\
    \hline
    Transaction cost & None & Search company, establish contract \\
    \hline
    Decision & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs \\
    \hline
    KPI1 - Cost & Cost of employees and equipment & Cost of service \\
    KPI2 - Quality & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+3\tabcolsep\relax}X}{Level of cleanness} \\
    KPI3 - Frequency & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+3\tabcolsep\relax}X}{Frequency of cleaning, n times per week a place is cleaned} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1!, hoever: (i) in preamble I would add package `ragged2e` and than defined table `X` columns as `>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X`, (ii) in defining width of the last `multicolumn` is `arrayrulewidth` superfluous since  table hasn't vertical lines, (iii)last `multicolumn cell spanfour `tabcolsep` oor only three, if the table options is defined as `{@{} l *{2}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} @{}}`.

Comment: @Zarko I think I implemented your advice. Feel free to edit the answer if I have misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the first table is nested in a `table` environment the second is not -- this creates the indent--simply put the second table also within the `\begin{table}.....\end{table}` -- the 2 tables will be now aligned

so far as the out of page fitment is concerned please refer to the nice solution by TivV--off course I like to visually color my tables--you can use the commands in my answer here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525106/197451

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{caption,tabularx,booktabs}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \hline
    ~ & Insourced & Outsourced \\
    \hline
    Agency monitoring & Control employees & Control company service \\
    Agency bonding & Employees' report & Company report \\
    Agency residual loss & None & None \\
    \hline
    Transaction cost & None & Search company, establish contract \\
    \hline
    Decision & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs \\
    \hline
    KPI1 - Cost & Cost of employees and equipment & Cost of service \\
    KPI2 - Quality & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Level of cleanness} \\
    KPI3 - Frequency & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Frequency of cleaning, n times per week a 
    place is cleaned} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lll}
    \toprule
    Agency monitoring & Control employees & Control company service \\
    Agency bonding & Employees' report & Company report \\
    Agency residual loss & None & None \\
    \hline
    Transaction cost & None & Search company, establish contract \\
    \hline
    Decision & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs & Collection of KPIs, cleaning logs \\
    \hline
    KPI1 - Cost & Cost of employees and equipment & Cost of service \\
    KPI2 - Quality & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Level of cleanness} \\
    KPI3 - Frequency & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Frequency of cleaning, n times per week a 
    place is cleaned} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```